# How to load a commonJS module's child path?

Tags: node.js, module, commonjs

I found that there are many public javascript library can exposed a child path like this:

```
import { Button } from 'antd/lib/button';
```

But when I try to load my own module in the `npm` like :

```
const AdaBoost = require('mlhelper/algorithm/AdaBoost');

//or
import AdaBoost from 'mlhelper/algorithm/AdaBoost';
```

It comes the error that 'module not found'.

So how to make my module's child path can be loaded as needed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm` uses the filesystem to resolve parts of a package. The file should thus be in `./algorithm/AdaBoost.js` or `./algorithm/AdaBoost/index.js` inside your package `mlhelper`. Also you should export from that file. See [this blog post](https://jaketrent.com/post/import-parts-node-packages-slash/) for an explanation of how this works.